# Rails where not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to retrieve a set of items using `where` in rails.  If I retrieve `all` I see:

```
2.2.2 :027 > JourneyLeg.all

JourneyLeg Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "journey_legs".* FROM "journey_legs"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
#<JourneyLeg id: 1, start_station: 24, end_station: 25, departure_time: "2000-01-01 06:37:00", arrival_time: "2000-01-01 06:45:00", journey: 6, created_at: "2015-07-25 11:32:42", updated_at: "2015-07-25 11:32:42">,
#<JourneyLeg id: 2, start_station: 25, end_station: 26, departure_time: "2000-01-01 06:46:00", arrival_time: "2000-01-01 06:50:00", journey: 6, created_at: "2015-07-25 11:32:42", updated_at: "2015-07-25 11:32:42">]>
```

And now I want to only return items where `start_station` is 24, so I use `JourneyLeg.where(:start_station => 24)`

```
2.2.2 :028 > JourneyLeg.where(:start_station => 24)
JourneyLeg Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "journey_legs".* FROM "journey_legs" WHERE "journey_legs"."id" = ?  [["start_station", 24]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

But for some reason this is querying `id` and not `start_station` (and hence not finding anything) but I have no idea why.

**Update 1**

Thanks to the comment from David, I spotted that the issue is caused by the fact I have an attribute on the model called `start_station` which is an integer but also a `has_one` relationship called `start_station`

```
has_one :start_station, :class_name => "Station", :primary_key => "start_station", :foreign_key => "id"
```

If I remove this relationship or rename it, then the following works as expected with the various suggestions:

```
JourneyLeg.where(:start_station => 24)
JourneyLeg.where(start_station: 24)
```

Comment: Which version of ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: Do you have a method defined in the model that is overwriting the definition of start_station by ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`JourneyLeg.where("start_station = '24'")`

Comment: Hardcoding the sql statement will obviously give you the query you want, but it doesn't solve the problem of why Rails is exhibiting this incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This should work based on [Documentation of `where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)

```
JourneyLeg.where({:start_station => 24})
```

I have tried this with my local application's model called `Article`, following variant of `where` works  (Rails 4.2.2, Ruby 2.0.0p247)

**Variant 1**

```
irb(main):006:0> Article.where({id: 2})
  Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 2, title: "World", text: nil, created_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16", updated_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16">]>
```

**Variant 2**

```
irb(main):009:0> Article.where({:id => 2})
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 2, title: "World", text: nil, created_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16", updated_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16">]>
```

**Variant 3**

```
irb(main):010:0> Article.where(id: 2)
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Article id: 2, title: "World", text: nil, created_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16", updated_at: "2015-07-25 21:09:16">]>
```

Comment: This throws an error `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>`

Comment: Did you try with `JourneyLeg.where({start_station => 24})` ?  I will check the syntax

Comment: this gives a syntax error because of the space after 'start_station' - correct syntax is `JourneyLeg.where(start_station: 24)`, which is equivalent to `JourneyLeg.where(:start_station => 24)` Is start_station an integer or a string? Maybe you need to use `JourneyLeg.where(start_station: '24'`)

Comment: Can you try `JourneyLeg.where({:start_station => 24})`